# Stop click event on an image inside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, events

I'm creating a simple light box to display photos.  When you click on an image in a gallery it expands to take up most of the screen while blacking out all content of the page behind. To do this I just append a `div` with the image clicked within it to the DOM like this:

```
<div id='image'>
 <img src="someImage">
</div>
```

I'm trying to create another onclick event that hides this DIV, but only if the click is anywhere other than the image.  So if you click on the image I don't want the div to disappear....only if you click on any of the blacked out portion to the sides of the image.  I tied the onclick to the "body" like so:

```
$('body').click(function(){
  $('#image').hide();
}):
```

The problem is even if I click the image it disappears.  How can I disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stopping the event from propagating to the body from the image.

For example:

```
$('#image').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: [**Here is a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3axahk2d/) that supports your answer. (Please provide your own in future, even if you add it later by editing your post).